# What does this this HTTP Authorization RewriteRule do?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, apache2, googlebot

I have an rewrite recursion error somewhere on my website that Google Bot caused, but I can't find the url that caused it because my Loglevel is low. I raised it but it has not happened again so far.

```
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

All Rewriterules look fine to me and have the [L] flag, except this one.

I can't quite understand it. It is from the open source shop system Magento.

As far as I can tell it does nothing but sets the environment variable E. But isn't that a very stupid way of doing that? Shouldn't you use SetEnv if that was the goal?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This line is setting the environment variable to the value of user authentication string - essentially setting a variable rather than constant value. As far as I know, SetEnv and SetEnvIf only allow you to set an environment variable to a predetermined constant.

The variable being set is actually HTTP_AUTHORIZATION, not E. I would guess this is part of the user authentication process.

Comment: You could use `SetEnvIf` instead if you wanted to. In fact this might even be preferable if you have .htaccess files in subdirectories that use mod_rewrite (since you might override your authentication!). eg. `SetEnvIf Authorization .+ HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$0`

Answer (score 26):

[Symfony developers Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/symfony-devs/jKphNy_0Q2Y/vYfkAuyjSHEJ) has a good answer for it. I quote:

> it looks like your hosting is running php as a fcgi, not a php5_module, like your localhost does. ( phpinfo - Server API: CGI/FastCGI )
>
> the point is that php5_module automatically handles HTTP_AUTHORIZATION headers, but fcgi_module does not.
>
> solution is simple - add this line to your .htacces on your hosting server:
>
> RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]

It worked for me

Comment: If there are other rewrite rules `RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]` should be added **before** them, **without the "L" option**.