# Apache Rewrite Rule Implications

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, woocommerce

A certain eCommerce company requires access to woocommerce product listings through simple authentication. If you are using apache they recommend modifying your .htaccess file with a rewrite rule:

`RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]`

I'm a little familiar with apache rewrite rules, but I've not seen one like this. Can someone tell me exactly what this is doing and if there are any security caveats I should be aware of?

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4947548/what-does-this-this-http-authorization-rewriterule-do

Comment: Thanks @MohammedElhag!